# Using static CSS files in Django 1.2.3 (Using Development Server)

Tags: css, django

First time Django user. VERSION: 1.2.3

I am trying to set up my dev server to use static CSS files, but can't seem to get the settings quite right. I've looked at the Django documents and other threads here, but still no luck. I'm hopping another set of eyes will help me.

Here's what I'm using right now:

settings.py

```
DEBUG = True
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/wade/myproject/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'
```

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (

```
'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
```

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (

```
'/home/wade/myproject/templates',
)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```

.html

```
<link rel"stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    href="/static/style.css" />
```

Comment: "Not quite right" isn't very informative.  What behaviour are you seeing?  What do you expect to see?  Do you get any error messages?  Please see http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: I expect to see my site styled with the style.css instead it's using the default. I'm not getting any error messages either.

Comment: Look whether the CSS file is served as 200 or 404. I assume the latter.

Comment: @AndiDog I see 200 in the terminal when I load a page. ([06/Mar/2011 11:33:57] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 611), but I'm not sure if that's what I am supposed to be looking for. How can I check for sure?

Comment: That's not the CSS. Just open up the web page source and click on the CSS file to see whether it loaded, or better use [Live Http Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) for Firefox.

Comment: @AndiDog Thanks! I opened the page source and it looks like the CSS file did load. What next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, since your CSS file did load, I looked at your question again and found that you're just missing a `=` in your HTML.

```
<link rel"stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/style.css" />
        ^^^
```

Comment: Newbie mistake. Thanks for taking the time to help out. Hopefully, I'll get better at this.